# (CloudKit Query) nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: arrays, swift, nspredicate, cloudkit, predicate

I am using an array of Group Names to search for their corresponding slices so I can pull and combine data from all of them. However, when I do the following query:

```
let pred = NSPredicate (format: "groupName IN %@", argumentArray: [groupNames])
    //let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    // edit predicate for array?
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Group", predicate: pred)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    //operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil{



            self.groupFeeds = (record.object(forKey: "groupFeed") as! Array)
            print("group feeds:: \(self.groupFeeds)")

            //self.feedTableView.reloadData()
            //print(groupNames.count)


        }

    }
    database.add(operation)
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    // print(leaderboardInfo.count)
```

I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil....

The thing is: When it prints out the group feeds, it only prints out the feed from the first group, then crashes. I need it to continue to search for other slices of data in the Cloud containing the group name, and print out the feed from EVERY 'group'.

Any idea of how to solve this nil issue, and get it to read all of my data?

Comment: Which line is causing the crash?

Comment: @rmaddy self.groupFeeds = (record.object(forKey: "groupFeed") as! Array), it runs through it the first time fine when it prints out the slice of data for the first group of the array, but it crashes when it tries the next groups.

Comment: Then `record.object(forKey: "groupFeed")` is `nil` and your attempt to force-cast the `nil` value to `Array` is causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy When I remove the ! it gives me an error though

Comment: You have to safely unwrap and cast. Use `if let` and `as?`.

Comment: @rmaddy is it ok if you quickly type out the line of code with if let and as?

Comment: Read [Downcasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338).

Comment: @rmaddy Would this work? Im new to this:    if let feeds = (record.object(forKey: "groupFeed") as? Array<Any>){
                  self.groupFeeds = feeds as! [String]
                }

Comment: Just do: `if let feeds = record.object(forKey: "groupFeed") as? [String] { self.groupFeeds = feeds }`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I believe that worked. One more think- it is printing the first groupFeed twice before moving on to the next. Any thoughts?

Comment: @rmaddy Now this keeps happening: It keeps printing out the first array twice. So now my data looks like this- first array: ["1", "2"] console result: ["1", "2", "1", "2", "3...next arrays work fine] REALLY could use your help on this last part to help me move forward

Comment: @rmaddy can u still help please?